# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it (in v4.5)

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, delegates, filesystemwatcher

I am aware that there are plenty questions have been already asked on this. But the solutions provided about delegates is not what I am getting to work with my code because I am working on 4.5 version and looks like the Dispatcher methods have slightly changed. Added to that, I am touching dotnet nearly after a decade and c# for the first time.

What I am actually tying to do in my WPF project is to append text of the textbox inside the main window to display the status/log. This is inside the singleton class called `Logger` The main static function of this class is log() which accepts a string which needs to be added to the text box with one simple line

```
txt.AppendText(msg);
```

After doing some research I changed it to

```
       Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
                txt.AppendText(msg);
        });
```

But I still get the same error. What is going wrong here? Is there anything else to do? Because I am calling this `Logger.log()` from `FileSystemEventHandler` insider another singleton class.

```
private void somethingChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{

    Logger.log("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);

}
```

Below is my `Logger` class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Threading;

namespace httpclientui.comps
{
    class Logger
    {

        private static TextBox txt;
        private Logger() { }

        public static void setup(TextBox t){

            txt = t;

        }
        public static void clear()
        {
            if (txt == null)
            {

                return;

            }
            txt.Clear();
        }
        public static void log(String msg, bool addNewLineChar = true)
        {
            if (txt == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                txt.AppendText(msg);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is my main window with only one textbox control called txtMessage.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private String folderToWatch;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            initialize();

        }
        private void initialize()
        {
            Logger.setup(txtMessage);
            Logger.clear();
            Logger.log("Launched");

            folderToWatch = "E:\\folder\\subfolder";
            Watcher.Instance.setup(folderToWatch);
            Watcher.Instance.start();

        }

    }
}
```

Below is my Watcher class which has FileSystemWatcher object to keep watching one of the folder and whenever something happens inside that folder like adding/deleting files and renaming the files will needs to be logged inside that textbox.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace httpclientui.comps
{
    class Watcher
    {
        private String path;
        //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx
        private FileSystemWatcher dog;
        private static Watcher instance;
        private Watcher()
        {
            //dog = new FileSystemWatcher()
        }
        public static Watcher Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Watcher();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
        public void setup(String folderPath)
        {
            path = folderPath;
            dog = new FileSystemWatcher(folderPath);
            Logger.log("setting up to watch folder: " + folderPath);
            dog.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(somethingChanged);
            dog.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(somethingChanged);
            dog.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(somethingChanged);
            dog.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(somethingRenamed);

        }
        public void start()
        {
            Logger.log("starting to watch folder");
            dog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
        public void pause()
        {
            dog.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        }
        public void stop()
        {
            dog.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        }
        private void somethingChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {

            Logger.log("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);

        }

        private void somethingRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {

            Logger.log("File: " + e.OldFullPath + " renamed to " + e.FullPath);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, it looks like you are not marshalling the `Clear()` method call to the Dispatcher. That's what is likely throwing the exception- *all* access to DispatcherObjects (which includes all Controls) must be done by the Dispatcher thread.

Also, you want to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher`, not `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`. The latter just spins up a new Dispatcher on the current (background) thread, which is not what you want.

Comment: Clear() is not throwing error but log(). After changing the code to Application.Current.Dispatcher the code is working. Is it another question to ask about why Clear() is working and why not the log()? Is it because log is called from an event handler (not sure if the file system watcher runs in a seperate thread). Can you put some light on it?